# How to copy link in Google Docs app?

Tags: ipad, google-docs

I've got the Google Docs app installed on my iPad.  There is a link in this doc and I need to copy the URL to the URL field in a calendar event.  However, I can't figure out how to do this.

I have tried long tapping on the link.  This gives me the choices "Open Link", "Edit Link", "Remove Link", "Cut", "Copy", "Paste", and "Add Comment".  The "Copy" choice copies the text, not the URL of the link.  The "Open Link" option opens the link the Google Sheets app, which does not seem to provide a way to find the URL of the page that is open.  The "Edit Link" brings up a dialog containing a text field with the "Link" but I can't figure out how to copy it.   I can tap to move the cursor, but I can't bring up any sort of menu to copy or even select part of the URL either by tapping or long pressing.

How can I copy this link so I can paste it into the Calendar URL field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I open google docs on my ipad i get a listing off files. If I select a file, a sequence of three dots appears in the upper right corner. When I click on the three dots a menu opens with a list of options. One option near the bottom is "Share and export". Select this option. A new menu appears. The second option down is to copy link. Click this and link is copied to clipboard.

The steps are

1. open google docs
2. select file
3. Click on 3 dots in upper right corner
4. Click on "Share and Export"
5. Click on "Copy Link"

Comment: I found this as a workaround while I was waiting for replies, but it seems the problem is really that the text in the link field isn't selectable / copiable.  I ran into another example of this in trying to copy the title of a document in a different app.  Why can't i select and copy any text input field, only some?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be written anywhere.  If it was printed somewhere that you had access to, you could probably see it and copy it someway.  That particular app on the ipad copies it for you.

Comment: I think my original answer is a correct answer to the question you asked.  Your new question is different from the one you originally asked.